# How to keep generated temporary files?

Tags: cmake

How to force it to keep temporaries like `CMakeFiles/cmTC_66ca1.dir/link.txt` or `CMakeFiles/cmTC_66ca1.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj`?

There is an error with the

> The C compiler is not able to compile a simple test program

but all necessary files to launch commands separately are gone. It's very hard to analyze that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Call CMake with [`--debug-trycompile`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html)

```
cmake --debug-trycompile ...
```

> Do not delete the try_compile build tree. Only useful on one try_compile at a time.