# How do I get a verbose output for CMake?

Tags: cmake

I would like to investigate why I have this error:

```
$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /cygdrive/c/Users/Ycr/Home/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /cygdrive/c/Users/Ycr/Home/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.6.2/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "/cygdrive/c/Users/Ycr/Home/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc" is not
  able to compile a simple test program.
```

Unfortunately after the error:

- I have no idea of what CMake did. I don't have a verbose log of the command it executed.
- The `CMakeFiles/cmTC_e4aa4.dir` was cleaned after the error, so I have no possibility to explore the issue myself.

How should I investigate such an error?

I tried to use the `--debug-trycompile` option. This time CMake creates a `CMakeTmp` folder which makes perfectly without errors. However, I still have this `CMakeFiles/cmTC_e4aa4.dir` that generates errors and even with the option CMake unlinks the folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake, how to keep generated temporary files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38115842/cmake-how-to-keep-generated-temporary-files) And take a look at `CMakeFiles\CMakeError.log` and check the error message there.

Comment: Doesn't really work, the `CMakeFiles/cmTC_53a28.dir/build.make` is not there anymore... With the `--debug-trycompile` I get a `CMakeTmp` file which builds without errors.

Comment: Strange. What does `CMakeError.log` say? Looking at your error message again, that compiler won't work without a [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) or switching to static library linking (it won't compile an executable). For a solution see e.g. [How to partially disabling cmake C/C++ custom compiler checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700198/how-to-partially-disabling-cmake-c-c-custom-compiler-checking).

Comment: I get this: https://gist.github.com/nowox/e90b768126d3e2a8b49fb759505e55c0

Comment: My problem is not really the output, but the input. I just would like to see what commands it executes. I feel this is a very simple request that CMake should be able to do.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/38864489/2799037 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/22803607/2799037

Comment: @nowox The error is in your error log: "undefined reference to `_exit'". So see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419782/exit-c-text0x18-undefined-reference-to-exit-when-using-arm-none-eabi-gcc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053840/converting-a-makefile-to-cmakelists-txt-for-tiva-c-series).

Comment: I've seen it. My question is more where can I get the full log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Getting a Verbose Log

The [`try_compile()`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake#L48) calls that CMake does in the beginning to test the compiler, gives a detailed error output on the console and writes it to

```
[your binary output directory]/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log
```

I've checked the source code again and there is no CMake option that would give more a more detailed output for CMake's internal `try_compile()` calls.

You could just force the output to standard output by adding some [`variable_watch()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/variable_watch.html) calls to your main `CMakeLists.txt` before your `project()` call like:

```
variable_watch(__CMAKE_C_COMPILER_OUTPUT)
variable_watch(__CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_OUTPUT)
```

### Keeping the Temporary Files

To keep the temporary file of [`try_compile`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/try_compile.html), add `--debug-trycompile` to the `cmake` command line.

But be aware that the multiple compiler tests at the beginning overwrite the artifacts of previous ones:

> It may however change the results of the try-compiles as old junk from a previous try-compile may cause a different test to either pass or fail incorrectly. This option is best used for one try-compile at a time, and only when debugging.

### References

- *[How to keep generated temporary files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38115842/cmake-how-to-keep-generated-temporary-files)*
- *[CMake error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (project): No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801638/cmake-error-at-cmakelists-txt30-project-no-cmake-c-compiler-could-be-found)*

Answer (score 4):

For me, none of the log files in my output directory contained useful information from `try_compile()`, even when using `--debug-trycompile`.

I ended up using the `OUTPUT_VARIABLE` option to capture and then print the output like this:

```
try_compile(<options> OUTPUT_VARIABLE TRY_COMPILE_OUTPUT)

message(WARNING ${TRY_COMPILE_OUTPUT})
```