CMake on Ubuntu 24.04 breaks when testing Clang++ for CXX
I'm using Clang and Clang++ to build C and C++ code in a Docker container that runs Ubuntu 24.04. Running "CMake" fails while checking C++. I wonder if anyone has seen this, and how you get around this. (I also cannot figure out how to report this to Kitware about CMake, if this is their problem.)
For this test, I am following "Step 1" of the CMake tutorial. Before running, I define and export CC=/usr/bin/clang and CXX=/usr/bin/clang++. This results in the following run:
~/tutor/Step1_build$ cmake ../Step1
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 16.0.6
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 16.0.6
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++ - broken

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:73 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/usr/bin/clang++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: '/home/buildbot/tutor/Step1_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-xkFIPT'
    
    Run Build Command(s): /usr/bin/cmake -E env VERBOSE=1 /usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_38a55/fast
    /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_38a55.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_38a55.dir/build
    gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/buildbot/tutor/Step1_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-xkFIPT'
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_38a55.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
       /usr/bin/clang++    -MD -MT CMakeFiles/cmTC_38a55.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -MF CMakeFiles/cmTC_38a55.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o.d -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_38a55.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /home/buildbot/tutor/Step1_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-xkFIPT/testCXXCompiler.cxx
    Linking CXX executable cmTC_38a55
    /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_38a55.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /usr/bin/clang++ CMakeFiles/cmTC_38a55.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_38a55
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_38a55.dir/build.make:100: cmTC_38a55] Error 1
    gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/buildbot/tutor/Step1_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-xkFIPT'
    gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_38a55/fast] Error 2
    

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)

Looking into the directory ~/tutor/Step1_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch, I discover that it is empty. I would expect CMake deposit a small C++ program there to compile and test.  (Lack of libstdc++ is another mystery, but should be unrelated to the missing sample test source code.)
In this case, I ran with Clang++ 16. The current default for Ubuntu 24.04 seems to be Clang++ 18.  I tried that also, and it failed in the same way.  HOWEVER, when I remove CC and CXX, and allow it to use GNC G++, it works:
~/tutor/Step1_build$ cmake ../Step1
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (0.2s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/buildbot/tutor/Step1_build

This doesn't happen on Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04. I have a series of builds on those systems that succeed using the same source code. This only started showing up with Ubuntu 24.04 and its associated tools.
I could build with GCC/G++, but G++ 13.2.0 is flagging errors that earlier versions of the compiler did not find. So I/we will try to clean that up over time. But having Clang++ and CMake fail so spectacularly was a total surprise.

CMake tutorial: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html
CMake version: 3.30.2
Clang++ version: 16.0.6 (23ubuntu4)
Docker version: 27.3.1 (on Ubuntu 20.04)

POST-MORTEM: This topic is now closed. But in case someone stumbles on this later, I finally figured this out with help from the two posted comments. (It is indeed closely related to the "related" post, but the underlying problem is really the Ubuntu 24.04 package defaults.)
The problem is not with CMake.  It is with a mismatch in the defaults for GNU and LLVM toolchains.  In fact, building the binary in CMake tutorial Step1 by clang++ tutorial.cxx doesn't work either.
The default versions for Ubuntu 24.04 are: GNU GCC/G++ 13 and LLVM Clang/Clang++ 18. When the default packages for gcc and clang are installed, some elements of G++ 14 are installed as well, but not libstdc++. However, Clang++ 18 needs the G++ 14 version of this library. To fix this, run
apt-get install libstdc++-14-dev

After this, clang++ should build properly for the tutorial example as well as CMake itself.

Related, if not a direct duplicate.

The TryCompile being missing is the expected result, they're temporary files and cmake deletes them automatically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38115842/how-to-keep-generated-temporary-files

Thanks. The comments by (at)Some programmer dude and (at)Alan Birties were helpful in debugging. I've added a "post-mortem" section to explain what I found.

@JustinJRTI: Stack Overflow discourages answering a question directly in the question body. Closing a question as a duplicate means that instead of putting an answer below the question one should post this answer below the duplicate question (assuming such answer is suitable for the duplicate question). That way we concentrate all answers for a single problem in the one place, so they will easier to be found whenever someone face with the same problem.
